# Object Iteration

Tags: php, oop, php-internals

I know that iteration over an object is equal to iterating over the visible properties of the class.

```
class MyClass
{
    public $var1 = 'value 1';
    public $var2 = 'value 2';
    public $var3 = 'value 3';

    protected $protected = 'protected var';
    private   $private   = 'private var';
}

$class = new MyClass();

foreach($class as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value\n"; // print all visible attributes
}
```

I'm curious to know **why** iteration over an object that doesn't implement any interface causes iteration over its visible variables? And what is the use case of this ability?

Comment: What feature are you talking about specifically? It doesn't seem clear from your question.

Comment: Not sure if the above code would work as you expect it to.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava why not try?

Comment: @Script47I mean why iterate over an object that doesn't implement any interface cause iterate over its visible variables

Comment: Do you mean *Why* because "Why have this ability?" or *Why* because "Why does this work this way?"

Comment: What do you mean by "use case"? If you have none, that's fine. There are tons of features in PHP that I've never used, but I would not question that there is anybody else out there who has

Comment: @Martin I mean why have this ability? or is there any use case that people use to iterate over the object to iterate through its visible properties?

Comment: Object is a collection of properties and methods. Built-in control structure `foreach` allows you to iterate over the array items, and visible properties in object and that is built in feature.  This is related with your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as you have declared class structure it's usually useless or at least a bad practice.

But PHP also allows you to dynamically create properties on objects, so its structure isn't implied by class definition.

You could do:

```
$class = new MyClass();
$class->nonExistingProperty = 123;
```

And then iteration over this object would return `nonExistingProperty` too.

That is a bad practice, but it is possible. It is sometimes used on containers for view data (Zend 1 as far as I remember).

Also there's a predefined `stdClass` which is designed to create "dynamic objects". For example it's used by `json_decode()` function.

So for example in case of decoding JSON document you may want to iterate over its properties without knowledge about its structure (it might be dynamic too).